# How to duplicate a selection to the right of the cursor n VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to duplicate a **selected / highlighted** text to the right of the cursor in VS Code?

Meaning:

before: `123`

after: `123123`

In Sublime it is possible to do using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: @Vega - none of those suggestions, all about copying lines up/down, do what the OP wants.  I have answered it below with a more recent command.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a `editor.action.duplicateSelection` command (unbound to any default keybinding) that does exactly what you want.  For example,

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",         // or whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "editor.action.duplicateSelection"
}
```

Comment: this will work on mac too (alt) automatically converted to mac 'option' key

Answer (score 2):

No, the feature is not available. [see feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2075)

You can do line duplication.VS Code has two shortcuts

> Shift+Alt+Down Copy Line Down editor.action.copyLinesDownAction
>
> Shift+Alt+Up Copy Line Up editor.action.copyLinesUpAction

[keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Answer (score 2):

its important for developers to create duplicate
like `ctrl + D` in Notepad++
link `ctrl + shift + D` in SublimeText

**it is not available in VSCode**

you can try `ctrl + drag mouse`

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible you will can customize your own shortcut in the configurations.

You can press cmd + k , cmd + s to open the shortcuts editor then you can find for “duplicate” word in the searchbar.

> I think is better that I teach you know how to fish, not give you a fish